# Loop only returns first row

Tags: java

Am trying to load the results of a database into a jtable, but when i run the code it only displays the first row and then errors an exception that no data was found. Here is my code;

```
try {

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "C:\\Users\\PMatope.FMBMW.000\\Documents\\Library.accdb";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");

            st = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT ID,full_name,sex,course,contact,email FROM Person");
            ResultSetMetaData data = rs.getMetaData();


            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
           // jTable1.setModel(model);

             while (rs.next()) {

                  String id,fname,sex,course,contact,email;
                  id = rs.getString("ID");
                  fname = rs.getString("full_name");
                  sex = rs.getString("sex");
                  course = rs.getString("course");
                  contact = rs.getString("contact");
                  email = rs.getString("email");

                   model.addRow(new Object[] {id,fname,sex,course,contact,email});
                   model.fireTableDataChanged();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString("sex"));
              }



        } catch (Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Message: "+ e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your table model first and create new instance for each loop times.

eg. :

```
DefaultTableModel model = null;
           // jTable1.setModel(model);

             while (rs.next()) {

                  model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

                  String id,fname,sex,course,contact,email;
                  id = rs.getString("ID");
                  fname = rs.getString("full_name");
                  sex = rs.getString("sex");
                  course = rs.getString("course");
                  contact = rs.getString("contact");
                  email = rs.getString("email");

                   model.addRow(new Object[] {id,fname,sex,course,contact,email});
                   model.fireTableDataChanged();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs.getString("sex"));
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise,

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
```

inside your while loop